# Eclipse - Target Definition Issue

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, p2, update-site

Firstly may I say that I am probably doing something completely wrong.

I have an update site where I am able install plug-ins successfully using Eclipse Indigo using the Help -> Install New Software... feature.

However, I now want to add a dependency on the same update site by using a target definition.

So, I create a new Target Definition file and add a new Software Site, and reference the same site as I did above.

The problem being that I am unable to retrieve any plug-ins. It just gives me the error:

0 plug-ins available.

Missing requirement: Immutify Eclipse Utilities 1.1.1.201105200936 (org.immutify.eclipse.util.1.1.1.201105200936) requires 'bundle.org.eclipse.ui 3.4.0' but it could not be found

Just wondering why it works on the Install New Software option but not on the software site option of the Target Definition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The option "Include required software" must not be checked. Here is an example of target definition that shows the steps to follow.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EIG:Add_to_Target_Platform